# Error: operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator in sqlServer

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below is my Query in which im trying to combine multiple column values

```
SELECT DISTINCT  CONVERT(varchar, Em.ADDR1) - CONVERT(varchar, Em.ADDR2) - CONVERT(varchar, Em.ADDR3) - CONVERT(varchar, Dm.DIST_NAME) - CONVERT(varchar,Sm.STATE_NAME)
- CONVERT(varchar, Cm.COUNTRY_NAME) AS Expr1
FROM            EMP_MST AS Em INNER JOIN
  DESIG_MST AS Dsgm ON Em.DESIG_NO = Dsgm.DESIG_NO AND Dsgm.COMPANY_NO = Em.COMPANY_NO INNER JOIN
  DEPT_MST AS Dptm ON Em.DEPT_NO = Dptm.DEPT_NO AND Dptm.COMPANY_NO = Em.COMPANY_NO INNER JOIN
  COUNTRY_MST AS Cm ON Em.COUNTRY_NO = Cm.COUNTRY_NO INNER JOIN
  STATE_MST AS Sm ON Em.STATE_NO = Sm.STATE_NO AND Em.COUNTRY_NO = Sm.COUNTRY_NO INNER JOIN
  DIST_MST AS Dm ON Em.DIST_NO = Dm.DIST_NO AND Em.STATE_NO = Dm.STATE_NO AND Em.COUNTRY_NO = Dm.COUNTRY_NO LEFT OUTER JOIN
  EMP_MST AS MEm ON Em.MANAGER = MEm.EMP_NO
WHERE        (1 = 1) AND (Em.EMP_NO LIKE '%%') AND (Em.COMPANY_NO = 1)
```

When I'm executing the Query , I'm getting

Error:

> operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator in sqlServer

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's your expected result?

Comment: Why are you using things like `(1 = 1)` and `(Em.EMP_NO LIKE '%%')`?

Comment: @UmutDerbentoğlu: I'm trying to show user address which is the combination of multiple column values

Comment: @IvanG: This query will be used further for searching of data also thats why im using like

Comment: it looks like `CONVERT(varchar, Em.ADDR1) - CONVERT(varchar, Em.ADDR2)` operations don't make sense with `varchar`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have said it's a bit hard to follow the exact query, but the specific issue, as the error states, is that you're using a `-` operator on `varchar` columns.

If you're trying to concatenate `varchar` values you should be using the `+` operator, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  CONVERT(varchar, Em.ADDR1) + CONVERT(varchar, Em.ADDR2) + CONVERT(varchar, Em.ADDR3) + CONVERT(varchar, Dm.DIST_NAME) + CONVERT(varchar,Sm.STATE_NAME)
+ CONVERT(varchar, Cm.COUNTRY_NAME) AS Expr1
```

If these columns are all `varchar` already you probably don't need the `CONVERT` functions, either.